# Why does band gap form for Silicon?

Tags: electronic-band-theory

[image]

The image on the right shows that as the interatomic distance becomes closer together, the 3P and 3S band that joined together begins to split up forming a gap in allowed energies. Why does this effect occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: The wave functions of neighbouring atoms (start to) overlap.

It has been too long to provider a detailed answer...

Answer (score 0):

The crystalline silicon forms a lattice where each silicon atom bonds with four neighboring silicon atoms. In order to do that, each bond must have the same length and energy, this wouldn't be possible if the valence orbitals of each silicon atom were still 3s^2 and 3p^2 as there would be only the 2 electrons in the 3p orbitals available for bonding. This suggests that hybridization of orbitals occurs just like with organic compounds where carbon is either sp, sp2 or sp3 (remember Si is udner C at the periodic table). To conclude, this means that in a crystalline Si solid material we wouldn't get an energy band that exists as a large 3p orbital, instead we get the last filled band (valence band) which is the band caused from the hybridization and the next band has a gap inbetween, which explains why Si acts as a semiconductor.